# Unable to install SciPy using pip in VIsual Studio 2015 ( Community Edition )

Tags: visual-studio, python-3.x, scipy, pip

I am using Windows 10 (64-bit) ,python 3.6 with the latest pip version and the latest version on NumPy as well (I installed it using the command pip install numpy). When I tried to install SciPy pip gave me this error :

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.19.0.zip
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy: started
    Running setup.py install for scipy: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Tanmay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-_79sv8pm\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Tanmay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-djlh9ivy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1051: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.10.1-sse2-32\lib is invalid.
      pre_dirs = system_info.get_paths(self, section, key)
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Running from scipy source directory.
    non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Tanmay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_79sv8pm\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\Tanmay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_79sv8pm\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "C:\Users\Tanmay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_79sv8pm\scipy\setup.py", line 336, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Tanmay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-_79sv8pm\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Tanmay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-djlh9ivy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Tanmay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_79sv8pm\scipy\
----- Failed to install 'scipy' -----

 - enter code here
```

How to i resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of *many* questions. The short answer is: on Windows, use wheels built by Christoph Gohlke, http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy, or switch over to Anaconda.

Comment: I switched to anaconda much better